# calling mysql_thread_end function before exiting the thread in c++ pthread

Tags: c++, mysql, pthreads

I am using two mysql objects in my application. I have to call [mysql_thread_end](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-thread-end.html) only once before exiting the thread. Is there any function/callback so that it will call before exiting the thread?

Sample program attached

```
using namespace std;
class MySql
{
public:
    MySql()
    {
        mysql = mysql_init(NULL);
    }
    ~MySql()
    {
        if(mysql)
        {
            mysql_close(mysql);
        }
    // Wrong: this will clear thread specific values twice. it may lead to crash the application.   
       // mysql_thread_end();
    }
    int Connect(const char *host,
                       const char *user,
                       const char *passwd,
                       const char *db,
                       unsigned int port,
                       const char *unix_socket,
                       unsigned long clientflag)
    {
        if(!mysql_real_connect(mysql, host,user, 
                            passwd, db, port, unix_socket, clientflag))
        {  
        return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    int Execute(const char *query)
    {     
        int status = mysql_query(mysql, query);
        return status;
    }
private:
    MYSQL * mysql;
};

void createthreads();
static void StartThread(void * Arg);

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int i = mysql_library_init(0, NULL, NULL);
    createthreads();    
    mysql_library_end();
    return 0;
}

void createthreads()
{  
    PRThread *thread;

    thread = PR_CreateThread(PR_USER_THREAD, StartThread, (void *)NULL, PR_PRIORITY_NORMAL, PR_GLOBAL_THREAD, PR_JOINABLE_THREAD, 0);
    //Sleep(2000);
    PR_JoinThread(thread);   
}

void StartThread(void * Arg)
{
    MySql mysqlsrc;
    MySql mysqldest;

    //Production server
    if(!mysqlsrc.Connect("localhost","root", "root", NULL, 3306, NULL, 0))
    {
        cout<<"Connection to Src Failed";
        return;
    }

    //Test Server
    if(!mysqldest.Connect("localhost","root", "root", NULL, 3306, NULL, 0))
    {
        cout<<"Connection to Destn Failed";
        return;
    }

    /// Sync databases.     
}
```

Comment: So why not just call it as last statement before returning from `StartThread()` as mentioned in the documentation you linked?

Comment: We should call mysql_thread_end after the closing the mysql connection (mysql_close)

Comment: It should go after the thread's work had been done, that is execute had been called. Where do you plan to call the latter?

Comment: mysql_close is called in the MySql destructor

Answer (score 0):

As the OP states `mysql_thread_end()` shall be called after the connections had been closed **and** the documentation states it shall be called right before the thread ends I'd propose to mod `StartThread` (the thread function) as follows:

```
void StartThread(void * Arg)
{
  {
    MySql mysqlsrc;
    MySql mysqldest;

    //Production server
    if(!mysqlsrc.Connect("localhost","root", "root", NULL, 3306, NULL, 0))
    {
        cout<<"Connection to Src Failed";
        return;
    }

    //Test Server
    if(!mysqldest.Connect("localhost","root", "root", NULL, 3306, NULL, 0))
    {
        cout<<"Connection to Destn Failed";
        return;
    }

    /// Sync databases.   
  } /* MySql objects run out of scope, their d`tor will be called, so mysql_close() is called also. */

  mysql_thread_end();
}
```

Comment: In my application every action creates a new thread and it will call separate function depeending on the selected action. The problem is I have to call this function everytime before exiting the thread. I want to know is there any function which will call automatically before exiting the thread.

Comment: "*I have to call this function everytime before exiting the thread ...*": This is exactly what the code shown my answer does.

Answer (score 0):

The standard pthread facility for [thread-specific data](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/pthread_setspecific.html) allows [thread-specific data destructors](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/pthread_key_create.html) to be registered, and thus may be used to [implement a sort of "pthread exit hook"](http://rabbit-hole.blogspot.com/2012/09/thread-termination-handlers.html).

That hook, then, can call `mysql_thread_end()`, and the rest of your code needn't be aware of this:

```
using namespace std;

// --> XXX WARNING UNTESTED AND ERROR CHECKING OMITTED XXX <----

namespace {
    pthread_key_t    key;
    pthread_key_once key_once = PTHREAD_ONCE_INIT;

    void cleanup(void *dummy)  // called at thread termination
    {
        mysql_thread_end();
    }
    void key_init()            // called pthread_once and only once
    {
        (void)pthread_key_create(&key, mycleanup);
    }
    void workaround_bz66740()  // call after you know mysql_thread_init has been called
    {
        (void)pthread_once(&key_once, key_init);
        (void)pthread_setspecific(key, (const void *)1);
    }
}

class MySql
{
public:
    MySql()
    {
        mysql = mysql_init(NULL);
        workaround_bz66740();
    }
    ....
```

Side note:  the fact that you need to explicitly clean up MySQL resources is burdensome and a pity, as is well articulated in [MySQL change request #66740](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=66740).